# Cannot kill the process

Tags: windows, windows-10

when playing the game "the finals" sometimes it crashes with UE5 error, and cannot re open have to reset pc because Discovery.exe is running. Getting access denied on task manager/process explorer ..Tried using process hacker to give myself permissions, it says i access denied, taskkill does nothing, powershell "" Stop-Process -Name "ProcessName" -Force "" does nothing.. I just want to kill the process and it seems impossible

Comment: There are multiple posts about `Discovery.exe` being a virus. Your description seems similar.

Comment: Discovery.exe is part of the finals , its not a virus.

Comment: It behaves like a badly written virus, so better verify it. [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can help in this.

Comment: Using the formatting tools available in the post editor could help make your question easier to read and thus clearer. What happens when you run Task Manager or Process Explorer as administrator? Have you done a repair install on the game? I think it is more likely the stuck process is a symptom rather than the main issue.